# Use of select queries in Zend Framework without providing database info

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-select

I use select queries as by following code:

```
$params = array(
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'dbname' => 'mst2');
    $db = Zend_Db::factory('pdo_mysql', $params);

$select = $db->select()
            ->from(array('dc' => 'delivery_center'))
            ->join(array('r' => 'region'), 'dc.region_id = r.region_id');
    $stmt = $select->query();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Here $db is the credentials of the database that I am using.But I have specified the credentials in application.ini already by following lines:

```
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = ''
resources.db.params.dbname = mst2
```

Now logically I should not provide these credentials again.But I have to use select queries.So how $db should be initialized without proving database credentials again??Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got the answer at my own.We have to use like that:          $table = new Admin_Model_DbTable_DeliveryCenter();
$select = $table->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART);

$select->setIntegrityCheck(false)
       ->join('region', 'region.region_id = delivery_center.region_id'); 
$result = $table->fetchAll($select);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Db resource is available by default and is initialized automatically whilst bootstraping.

If you want to get database adapter in your application you can get it as plugin resource from bootstrap:

```
$resource = $bootstrap->getPluginResource('db');
$db = $resource->getDbAdapter();
```

If you do not have reference to bootstrap you always can retrieve it from FrontController:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance(); 
$bootstrap = $front->getParam('bootstrap');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
Zend_Db::factory($zend_config_object->resources->db)
but i think if you have specified this in application.ini, then zend create db object for you automaticlly and you can get it through 
Zend_Register and key "db".